# How to check if a matrix has an inverse in the R language

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

How do you determine if a matrix has an inverse in R?

So is there in R a function that with a matrix input, will return somethin like:

> "*TRUE*" (this matrix has inverse)/"*FALSE*"(it hasn't ...).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the determinant (with the `det` function)? You could make a function that returns a boolean with this (e.g., `ifelse(det(M) == 0, FALSE, TRUE)`).

Comment: @josilber Good call. Additionally, it looks like the `Matrix` package might have some more efficient methods if you have additional information about the matrix in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really forgot about this property of matrix and its iverse :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@MAB has a good point. This uses `solve(...)` to decide if the matrix is invertible.

```
f <- function(m) class(try(solve(m),silent=T))=="matrix"
x <- matrix(rep(1,25),nc=5)          # singular
y <- matrix(1+1e-10*rnorm(25),nc=5)  # very nearly singular matrix
z <- 0.001*diag(1,5)                 # non-singular, but very smalll determinant
f(x)
# [1] FALSE
f(y)
# [1] TRUE
f(z)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This no longer works in R 4.0.0.  From R News:` matrix objects now also inherit from class "array", so e.g., class(diag(1)) is c("matrix", "array"). This invalidates code incorrectly assuming that class(matrix_obj)) has length one. `  Changing the first line to `f <- function(m) "matrix" %in% class(try(solve(m),silent=TRUE))` seems to work.

Comment: So, `is.matrix(try(solve(m), silent = TRUE))`.

Comment: `is_invertible <- function(X) !inherits(try(solve(X), silent = TRUE), "try-error")` should work across R versions and will also support `Matrix` objects, as well as other arbitrary matrix classes that implement `solve()` methods.

Answer (score 13):

Using `abs(det(M)) > threshold` as a way of determining if a matrix is invertible is a very bad idea. Here's an example: consider the class of matrices cI, where I is the identity matrix and c is a constant. If c = 0.01 and I is 10 x 10, then det(cI) = 10^-20, but (cI)^-1 most definitely exists and is simply 100I. If c is small enough, `det()` will underflow and return 0 even though the matrix is invertible. If you want to use determinants to check invertibility, check instead if the modulus of the log determinant is finite using `determinant()`.

Comment: +1. This seems like the best currently posted approach -- with `M <- 1e-5 * diag(100)` (clearly invertible), `det(M)` returns 0 (implying it's not invertible) but `determinant(M)$modulus` returns -1151.293, implying it's invertible.

Comment: One problem I can see if with e.g. `determinant(crossprod(matrix(rnorm(300), 10, 30)))`, which is finite (although the matrix has only rank 10 out of 30).

Answer (score 8):

You can try using `is.singular.matrix` function from `matrixcalc` package.

To install package:

```
install.packages("matrixcalc")
```

To load it:

```
library(matrixcalc)
```

To create a matrix:

```
mymatrix<-matrix(rnorm(4),2,2)
```

To test it:

```
is.singular.matrix(mymatrix)
```

If matrix is invertible it returns `FALSE`, and if matrix is singlar/non-invertible it returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution given by @josilber in the comments (i.e. `abs(det(M)) > 1e-10`) you can also use `solve(M) %*% M` for a square matrix or `ginv` in the MASS package will give the generalized inverse of a matrix.

To get `TRUE` or `FALSE` you can simply combine any of those methods with `tryCatch` and `any` like this:

`out <- tryCatch(solve(X) %*% X, error = function(e) e)`

`any(class(out) == "error")`

Answer (score 0):

some cautions might be taken when using `is.singular.matrix` function from `matrixcalc` package (version 1.0.6) as mentioned in @Akki's answer.

```r
library(gtools)
library(Matrix)

# define a compositional matrix consisting of 10 observations and 8 components
set.seed(2024)
x = rdirichlet(10, alpha = rep(1,8)) 
y = t(x) %*% x
```

```
> rankMatrix(y)
[1] 8
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 1.776357e-15
> nrow(y)
[1] 8
> is.singular.matrix(y)
[1] TRUE
```

The rank of `y` equals to the number of rows of `y`, suggesting `y` is a full rank matrix. Besides, `solve(y)` also gives answer. but `is.singular.matrix(y)` returns value `TRUE` suggests `y` is a singular matrix